# How to translate error message

Tags: magento-1.7

When a customer registers for an account that requires manual activation, they see the message "This account is not activated". How can I edit that message? I have been unable to find the file that contains that message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create/edit theme translate file: `app/design/[area]/[package]/[theme]/locale/[language_code]/translate.csv` (e.g. app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv) and put there this row:

`"This account is not activated", "Whatever you want..."`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you override below controller:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

Just find the controller file **AccountController.php**  in local or community codepool & edit the message.